# Why was the question “Show email next to name in Gmail?” closed by 1 mod as “details or clarity”?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation

1 mod closed  [Show email next to name in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/154399/18147) as "details or clarity". The only comment left by the mod is:

> Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [How to Ask](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). – [Rubén**♦**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n) [yesterday](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/154399/show-email-next-to-name-in-gmail#comment140883_154399)

However, the question is 100% clear and [sharing research is not required](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4794/18147).

What's unclear or which detail needs to be added?

Comment: Ruben how about you answer the question instead of downvoting it?