# Is showing research is a requirement when posting a question on WebApps.SE?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderators

I wonder the following: Is showing research is a requirement when posting a question on WebApps SE?

Requirement means that if the OP doesn't show research, then the question must be closed.

---

Note: I tried asking the same question 2+years ago:
[Is showing research is a requirement when posting a question on WebApps SE?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4794/18147) It was closed a few weeks ago by 1 mod under the reason "[the question] includes deceitful content". So I'm not adding any other content here. Just the yes/no question: *Is showing research is a requirement when posting a question on WebApps SE?*