# When do moderators plan to clearly state whether showing research is a requirement when posting a question on WebApps.SE?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderators, close-reasons

On [Why do the moderators refuse to clearly state whether showing research is a requirement when posting a question on WebApps.SE?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5017/18147), I was told by a moderator to be patient. However I have already waited for 2.5 years to know whether showing research is a requirement when posting a question on WebApps.SE and in the meantime, [many](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5017/18147) of my questions got closed by one moderator seemingly under that reason. [Many](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4984/18147) other questions have also been closed by the same moderator seemingly under that reason as well. When do moderators plan to clearly state whether showing research is a requirement when posting a question on WebApps.SE?

Requirement means that if the OP doesn't show research, then the question must be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A community manager stepped in to help clarify the policy: [Does Web Apps Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/18147)

October 2023 seems likely to be when the policy will be decided.