# Why are questions being closed seemingly because they don't show research, even though it hasn't been decided yet if showing research is a requirement

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderators

I see a fair amount of questions being closed seemingly because they don't show any research. Examples:

- [Populate a Google slide automatically via Google spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80829/18147)
- [How can I export a single event as an ICS file from Google Calender?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/133470/18147)

Why are questions being closed seemingly because they don't show research, even though [moderators haven't announced when they plan to clearly state whether showing research is a requirement](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5036/18147)?

Requirement means that if the OP doesn't show research, then the question must be closed.

Moderators haven't announced when they plan to clearly state whether showing research is a requirement. Therefore, I believe it means it hasn't been decided whether showing research is a requirement. Therefore, I believe that in meantime, waiting for the mod decision, one shouldn't close questions on the ground they don't show research. My expectation is that mods should establish policies before starting to implement them, otherwise closures are arbitrary.

Comment: The referred post is not about **deciding** whether research is required in [webapps.se]. Ref. [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), [How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177550/289691)

Comment: The is referred post is [When do moderators plan to clearly state whether showing research is a requirement when posting a question on WebApps.SE?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5036/18147). It is about when the mods will decide whether research is a requirement. Unless you have already decided but prefer to hide the information from the community? I'm confused. Please clarify. Even better, how about answering the question?

Comment: @Rubén I am confused about what part of this meta post needs "details or clarity." It seems clear to me. It's frustrating that the moderators are not willing to explain or discuss their reasons behind the recent closure of several old, well-received, on-topic questions. This, among other recent moderator actions in Web Apps SE, goes against the community-run spirit of the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: This question was closed because the wording was misleading. Please review the [tour], [help/on-topic] and [ask] thoroughly.

Comment: @Rubén You're splitting hairs IMHO but anyway how about now with the edit?

Comment: Please develop "Why are questions being closed seemingly because they don't show research, even though moderators haven't announced when they plan to clearly state whether showing research is a requirement?" In other words, Why are you asking that? What make you think that things should be different? What are your expectations?

Comment: @Rubén Sure. Moderators haven't announced when they plan to clearly state whether showing research is a requirement. Therefore, I believe it means it hasn't been decided whether showing research is a requirement. Therefore, I believe that in meantime, waiting for the mod decision, one shouldn't close questions on the ground they don't show research.

Comment: Add all the relevant detail directly into the question body.

Comment: I think that you can do it better. I will get some time off from Meta Web Applications, so please take your time.

Comment: Relevant meta discussion started by a community manager about whether we should mandate research on questions: [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584)