# Why are my comments linking to a Meta post about the question where I commented getting deleted after just a few hours?

Tags: discussion, moderators, comments

I noticed that the two questions:

- [Populate a Google slide automatically via Google spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80829/18147)
- [How can I export a single event as an ICS file from Google Calender?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/133470/18147)

got closed. I posted a [Meta question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5040/18147) asking why they got closed. I left a comment on the two questions to indicate that there was a Meta question about it. However, the comments got removed after a few hours by a mod. Why?

I believe it was useful to leave a comment on the two questions to indicate that there was a Meta question about it, so that the 1) post authors 2) future readers wondering about the question closures 3) people reviewing the reopen queue are informed of it.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with a question linked as a duplicate.

Comment: @Rubén It's very concerning that you're deleting comments linking to meta posts, preventing the community, including reopen queue reviewers, from learning about and discussing issues relevant to the site, which is what the meta site is for. This goes against the community-run spirit of the Stack Exchange network.