# Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Moderators Strike

Tags: discussion

2023-08-07: [Moderation strike: Conclusion and the way forward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392032/289691)

Note: I'm back to regular activity.

---

2023-08-02: [Moderation strike: Results of negotiations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391847/289691)

Notes:

1. A recurrent question about the above post is if the strike was over. Please read [Machavity's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391852/289691). TL;DR: There isn't a simple yes / no answer due to the diverse communities and groups involved.
2. I will use my moderation privileges on a limited basis until the promises derived from the negotiations are delivered. I might limit the use of my moderation powers on the homepage.

---

Related post in Meta Stack Exchange: [Moderation Strike: Stack Overflow, Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/289691)

Notes:

- As the moderation strike is taking longer than expected, from time to time, I will do something like posting a comment or chat message to keep this account "active".
- This [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390704/289691) to [Moderation Strike update: Data dumps, choosing representatives, GPT data, and where we’re holding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390106/289691) has updates. The last update, 2023-06-26, includes a copy of the specific demands and the corresponding progress originally posted in the Meta Discussion, the Discord server used to coordinate the moderation strike efforts.
- I will start a public "digital garden", a website to share notes. Some might be related to Web Application SE moderation stuff. The link will be shared later using my alternate account, mentioned below.

---

During the **moderator strike**[^1], which starts on Jun 5, 6:00 am UTC for me, I will only use the account used to make this post to communicate with Community Managers and fellow Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Community Moderators using the communication channels provided by this platform.

Non-Community Managers and non-SO/SE Community Moderators might still reach me through the accounts linked to my alternate Stack Exchange network profile: [Wicket](https://stackexchange.com/users/28428472/wicket?tab=accounts). On Web Applications, the account is [Wicket](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/311306/wicket); if you have rep +20 on Stack Overflow or any Stack Exchange site, you might ping me in [Google-Fu](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/google-fu) the Web Applications Stack Exchange main chat room.

[^1]: [What has happened to lead moderators to consider striking?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424979/1595451)

## Related

- [Discussion: Network policy regarding AI Generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389617/289691)
- [Is there an external space dedicated or strongly related to Stack Exchange Community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389721/289691)
- [Stack Exchange is failing its community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389558/289691)
- [What is the network policy regarding AI Generated content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389582/289691)

Answer (score 1):

I understand and respect the moderators’ decision to strike. Stack Exchange, Inc. should not make it harder for the volunteer, unpaid, community moderators to do their tasks, including keeping the site clean and organized.

I would like to ask for some clarification regarding the strike: Are any of the Web Apps SE moderators also abstaining from participating in meta? (By “participating”, I mean answering meta posts directed to moderators as well.) I’m asking because I don’t see anything in the [linked Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/162827) or the [strike open letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) that indicates that the moderators on strike are also abstaining from meta discussion. However, we have several meta posts here (most of them made before the moderator strike) that would really benefit from having a moderator response, e.g.:

- [Why do the moderators refuse to clearly state whether showing research is a requirement when posting a question on WebApps.SE?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5017/7584) posted Apr. 25, 2023.
  The current moderator response to this two-month-old post is:

  > TL;DR: Please be patient.

The rest of these meta questions don't yet have a moderator response:

- [When do moderators plan to clearly state whether showing research is a requirement when posting a question on WebApps.SE?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5036/7584) May 16, 2023
- [Why are questions being closed seemingly because they don't show research, even though it hasn't been decided yet if showing research is a requirement](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5040/7584) May 28, 2023
- [Do moderators care about the community consensus?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5060/7584) June 15, 2023
- [Why was this question on "Where can I see all my comments on issues on GitHub?" closed by one moderator?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5071/7584) June 23, 2023

If the Web Apps SE moderators are not abstaining from participating in meta as part of the strike, a moderator response to these meta posts would be very helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about other moderators. Besides what is mentioned in the question, I'm not abstaining from participating due to the moderation strike. I will only provide details about this in the private channels for moderators. In other words, I will only provide details to community moderators and community managers.