# Do moderators care about the community consensus?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Dozens of questions were [unilaterally closed for lack of research](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4984/18147) by one moderator. However, the community consensus is that lack of research shouldn't be ground for closure or that least, it hasn't been decided that lack of research should be ground for closure.

For example, this [answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5009/18147) by [galacticninja](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7584/galacticninja) (5 upvotes, 1 downvotes) states:

> While I agree that “research effort” should be encouraged, it should not be required or mandatory.

As another example, this [answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4986/18147) by [galacticninja](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7584/galacticninja) (11 upvotes, 2 downvotes) states in bold letters and using a large font:

> The community has not reached a consensus on whether or not “showing research” is a requirement.

(which means there is no consensus on closing questions due to lack of research)

These unilaterally question closure for lack of research are confusing many users, for [example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103374/18147) (comment with 2 upvotes):

> @Rubén I second this. This question seems fine to me and is helpful in solving the problem for me. [jdhao](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/271868/jdhao) [Apr 11 at 7:33](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103374/where-can-i-see-all-my-comments-on-issues-on-github#comment157715_103374)

Do moderators care about the community consensus? I am asking to see if there is any point in participating in this Meta.

Comment: The current moderators are on strike. Rel. https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5055/311306

Comment: @Wicket I don’t see anything in that meta post or the [open letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) that suggests that the moderators on strike are also abstaining from meta discussion. In fact, I see a lot of users who have joined the strike still participating at Meta Stack Exchange discussions. Are the current Web Apps SE moderators refraining from participating in meta?

Comment: The strike is over.

Comment: [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584) - relevant meta discussion post where a community manager asked the community whether we should mandate research on questions.