# Why was this question on "Where can I see all my comments on issues on GitHub?" closed by one moderator?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

The question [Where can I see all my comments on issues on GitHub?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103374/18147) was closed by one moderator. The reason given is:

> This question doesn't meet the [current quality standards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error). [Rubén - People First](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n-people-first)**♦** [Apr 7 at 19:2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103374/where-can-i-see-all-my-comments-on-issues-on-github#comment157637_103374)

I don't know which current quality standard they are referring to that caused the question to be unilaterally closed. I asked in the comment, but didn't get a reply. Other readers are confused too, e.g.

> This question seems fine to me and is helpful in solving the problem for me. [jdhao](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/271868/jdhao) [Apr 11 at 7:33](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103374/where-can-i-see-all-my-comments-on-issues-on-github#comment157715_103374)

Why was this question on "Where can I see all my comments on issues on GitHub?" closed by one moderator?

---

Update (2023-10-24): a mod deleted the above-mentioned comments. The deleted comments can be viewed on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20230627152629/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103374/where-can-i-see-all-my-comments-on-issues-on-github) and on this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2L7k.png).

Comment: I think you should already know it, but in case you missed the comment to your other recent question related to Webapps moderators, the moderator mentioned in this question is on moderation strike. Rel. https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5055/311306

Comment: @Wicket I don’t see anything in that meta post or the [strike open letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) that suggests that the moderators on strike are also abstaining from meta discussion. In fact, I see a lot of users who have joined the strike still participating at Meta Stack Exchange discussions. Are any of the Web Apps SE moderators refraining from participating in meta?

Comment: This is very concerning. The question is on-topic, clear, and well-received by the community, yet it has been unilaterally closed ([among dozens of others](//webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4984/7584)) as [“needs details or clarity”](//webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5008/7584). It currently has 307 votes (currently the 3rd most upvoted question in Web Apps SE) and 78k views. It also has several well-received, highly upvoted answers. Moderators: What details or clarity does it need? The issue stated is clear and understandable to anyone who uses GitHub.

Comment: Related: [How shall we request the reopening of questions closed due to lack of research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5151/7584) | [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584) - meta discussion post where a community manager asked the community whether we should mandate research on questions.

Answer (score 4):

Your question was very clear and detailed, and it should not have been closed as lacking details or clarity.

Comment: This is the kind of question I would ask myself as a developer, and the answers provided are very helpful. I just joined this community to comment on this specific question, but I've been keeping an eye on this on-going debate for the last few weeks. From an external point of view, this is cause for concern. I'm saying this with respect, as I have not been implicated in WebApps.SE at all, so I have no history whatsoever, but having a trusting relationship between the community and its moderators is as important, if not more, than 100% curated content. (1/2)

Comment: This community seems to me like it could provide valuable help to the Internet, for both beginners and advanced users of webapps. Hopefully the current debate on showing research will end up serving the best interests, and I also wish that the relation between users and mods get to a more peaceful place. (2/2)

Comment: @Laf I couldn’t agree more with you that “having a trusting relationship between the community and its moderators is as important”. Being a moderator means not only enforcing the rules, but also fostering a collaborative community.

Answer (score 4):

Based on their comments, I understand that the moderator who closed your question did so because they thought it lacked research (moderators, please let me know if I’m mistaken). This mandatory research requirement has been a concern for many in the community, myself included, and some of us have contacted the community managers about the moderators’ actions.

The community managers responded by creating the meta FAQ post “[Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584)". The community voting on that post shows that the community agrees that research is not a mandatory requirement for asking questions on Web Apps SE, and therefore moderators should not close questions for not meeting any research standards.

Based on this community consensus and site policy, I think your question is valid and deserves to be reopened. I have flagged it with a custom reason requesting for it to be reopened and citing the meta FAQ post, “[Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584)”.