# How do I ask a question on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, asking-questions, stackexchange

‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀

Comment: You have only entered a question sentence on the post title and added some characters to make the Ask Question form publish the question. This might be allowed on other sites, but it's not here. Please [edit] the post to replace the question body content with something like the context that led you to make this post. You might explain why you do not find the guidance on the Ask Question form helpful or what has motivated you to post this question on Web Applications Stack Exchange.

Comment: Then why answer this, @Rubén?

Comment: @Cerbrus You, the Community, are impossible to please. No matter what I do you always complain :P

Comment: This is a low-effort question that deliberately circumvented the restrictions in the form, in order to post a question without body. That's not something that should be rewarded with a long answer. That's something you close and delete if the OP doesn't update it. Instead, you answer it, _then_ close it...

Comment: Putting jokes aside, this was answered because at the time this question was posted it coincided with something discussed about site moderation.

Comment: By the way, a few moments ago I made i posted in Meta SE [Could users still get “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394346/289691)

Comment: That doesn't matter. This question isn't even about WebApps. The question is off-topic, it deliberately broke validation, and the OP clearly isn't interested in fixing it.

Comment: @Rubén I'm just asking you why this was answered, and I'm explaining why this shouldn't have been, and why this should've been deleted. On SE Meta, on SO Meta and on _so many_ other sites, this would've been long gone already. But instead of just answering, you get argumentative and, frankly, hostile. _"Please excuse me that I don't give you and every SE denizen who occasionally comes to help us a complete overview"_ is not a tone becoming of a moderator.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm sorry to sound hostile to you. My intention was not that but to answer your question. There is background that might explain that, but it's not your fault, and it's not an excuse, so I deleted my comment. Still, my fellow mods/cm could see it when they reviewed the flag queue and took the appropriate measures. Regarding being "argumentative", please elaborate on that. How could I say the same without sounding hostile?

Comment: @Rubén Your first reply to me is hostile, doesn't address my (simple) question, and indicates that you're not here to serve the community but to serve your _own_ purposes. There are ___so many___ things wrong with this question, and your ___only___ justification for answering it, is that the subject is related to "something" discussed _elsewhere_. By closing this you're preventing the community from answering. Frankly, it baffles me that you don't understand why this question should just be deleted.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks for your reply. I didn't think that you feel offended by that comment. I'm sorry. I will not comment on your conclusions about it. Regarding the second part, I'm sorry my reply didn't please you. There are details that I will not share. Please excuse my poor communication skills.

Comment: Humour translates badly in written text, especially if your communication skills are indeed poor. I'd advice you to avoid making jokes like that, @Rubén...

Answer (score 0):

Stack Exchange is not a place to make posts to ask questions. There are more than 100 sites related to Stack Exchange where questions might be asked.

You can learn what Stack Exchange is at https://stackexchange.com/about.

You can find the complete list of sites where you can ask questions at https://stackexchange.com/sites.

If you need help finding a site to ask a question that you want to ask, you might ask for a site recommendation at https://meta.stackexchange.com.

All the sites listed in https://stackexchange.com/sites have the same Ask Question form, but new users might occasionally be routed to a different form. When using the standard Ask Question form, please follow the guidance provided. This should be done in most cases, but other sites might have different rules. *Your mileage might vary*.

Do not circumvent the feedback received on the Ask Question form by cheating. If the Ask Question form tells you that the question body should not be empty, do not repeat what you have done in this question. If you repeatedly try to cheat, you might get bet banned from posting new questions.

Please take the Ask Question form guidance seriously.

From the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92075/289691) to [What can I do when getting “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/289691) ([rev 15](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/92075/15) )

> #### Why am I getting this message?
>
> All new questions are subjected to a "minimum quality" filter that checks for characteristics of extremely poor questions. Your question has been caught by the filter.
>
> #### What can I do to get the system to accept my question?
>
> First, make sure your question is on-topic on the site you're asking it. You can check the site's policy by going to the Help Center, and, under the header 'Asking', going to 'What topics can I ask about here?'.
>
> Make sure your question has
>
> - a clear title
> - a reasonable *explanation* of what your question is, **sharing your research on the matter**
> - commentary on what you have tried to solve your problem
> - correct use of English and actual sentences
> - proper spelling, grammar, capitalization, and punctuation
>
> If your question is so brief that it could be looked up in a dictionary or reference book/site trivially, it might not be a good fit on our network.
>
> #### Can you be more specific?
>
> Exact details about the algorithm are not being released by the team.
>
> > I am against being explicit here.... Our check takes into account tags, title and body. We are not going to give breakdown of what was wrong, that is spoon feeding. ([source: waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/make-the-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-message-more-helpful/91987#91987))
> >
> > If we provide a "formula" then it's just another way for users to bypass the question quality filters. ([source: Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/make-the-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-message-more-helpful/91321#91321))
>
> #### What are good resources on how to ask high-quality questions?
>
> Fortunately, there are lots! See:
>
> - [The "How to Ask" page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (the link is basically the same page on every site)
> - [How to ask a smart question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question/18588#18588)
> - [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)
> - [What’s the best way to ask a question if English isn't your first language?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/whats-the-best-way-to-ask-a-question-if-english-isnt-your-first-language)
> - [Jon Skeet's *Writing the perfect question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) (will take a few minutes to read)
> - [Eric Raymond's *How To Ask Questions The Smart Way*](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html), (this gets cited a lot but it's fairly long)

## ABOUT RESEARCH IN WEB APPLICATIONS

We discussed requiring research in Web Applications questions
[Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/88163). The summary on the discussion was [posted](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5142/88163) by the Community Manager conducting it.