# Why is this question on searching for files with a specific extension and some file size range in Google kept closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Since a CM recently stated that [showing research is not required](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/18147), I flagged the question [How can I search for files with a specific extension and some file size range in Google?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/143853/18147) for reopening, but the flag was declined (no reason was given). Why is the question kept closed?