# How shall we request the reopening of questions closed due to lack of research?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

As mentioned by SpencerG on https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5142/18147:

> including research in a question is not required for question asking on Web Apps.

and:

> closed questions can be reopened should they otherwise be of an adequate standard for Web Apps.

How shall we request the reopening of questions closed due to lack of research? Should we cast a reopen vote? Raise a flag? Message the mods in the [public chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/google-fu)? Use some other way? Something else?

I'm asking as I've [tried](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/5151/1) to cast a reopen vote and raise a flag, and none of it seems to work.

Comment: That was before SpencerG's question and the conclusion drawn from that. I think you can safely discard all _"Why was this closed"_ and _"Please reopen"_ questions from before that. The rules were clarified/changed/updated, whatever you want to call it. New perspectives warrant re-evaluation of those questions, and IMHO, a new Meta question. Maybe a single _"Please review these questions"_ list? Something organized that the community _and_ moderators can use to track the cleanup/re-open effort post-SpencerG

Comment: @Cerbrus ok I'll post that question list if this meta question is ignored by the mods.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest creating a ***single*** Meta question where this re-open effort can be organized.

Something where the community can list the questions that they believe were closed because of a lack of research, that moderators can refer to, to find questions that need their review, and something other users can refer to to see the status of these reviews.

Basically, a manual review queue:

| **Question** | **Status** | **Reason** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| <strike>[Foo the bar of baz](https://www.example.com)</strike> | Reopened | - |
| <strike>[How to bake a cake?](https://www.example.com)</strike> | Rejected | off-topic |
| [Is this a good question?](https://www.example.com) | Todo |  |

```
| **Question** | **Status**  | **Reason** |
|--------------|-------------|------------|
| <strike>[Foo the bar of baz][1]</strike> | Reopened | - |
| <strike>[How to bake a cake?][1]</strike> | Rejected | off-topic |
| [Is this a good question?][1] | Todo | |
```

Comment: There is "one" community that includes loud users, silent ones, and a range in between.  Some are moderators or have high rep privileges and some do not.  I am happy that the "Research question" was resolved to everyone's satisfaction and we can move on.  For things that require mod intervention, I suggest appropriate patience that properly reflects the time required to intervene properly.  If organizing, care should be taken to ensure that it does not simply reflect an effort to circumvent normal site processes.

Comment: You are repeating your question

Comment: @galacticninja the moderators can't move as fast as you however the post in question was closed.  Please slow down so that I at least can focus on the closed questions rather  than other issues that are coming up.

Comment: Unfortunately, this proposal was deemed "circumvention of normal site processes" and  efforts have been shut down.

Answer (score 1):

On behalf of the moderator's team, I commit to making a post as soon as possible about the team's stance and suggestions for community coordination efforts that require the moderator's intervention (diamond privileges).

Please excuse me that I don't give you a date or timeline at this moment, I don't know the availability for this week of my fellow mods.