# Question closed for "needs details or clarity" but it's so simple I don't know what more detail to add

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, close-reasons

My question [How do I download all my videos from Google Photos?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/171752/88780) was closed with the following reason:

> This question needs [details or clarity](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.
>
> Add details and clarify the problem being solved. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question.

But, the question to me is so simple and straightforward that I'm not even sure what more detail I could provide.

Comment: The referred question was reopened on September 5.

Answer (score 5):

Your question seems very clear and understandable to me, as someone who also uses Google Photos. I also don’t understand why a moderator closed it for needing more details or clarity. I support your request to reopen the question.

As far as I can tell, you can't access or download Google Photos files from Google Drive (drive.google.com), so you can't download specific Google Photos files there if you want to. I can see how this question may be of interest to multiple users.

Answer (score 4):

I voted to reopen the question. The question is crystal-clear to me. Showing research [is not a requirement](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5036/18147).

---

To address the comment that moderator [Rubén](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n) left:

> Please show what you have tried. [Rubén](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n) [52 mins ago](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5095/question-closed-for-lacking-detail-but-its-so-simple-i-dont-know-what-more#comment5561_5095)

It's not a reason to close.

> explain what difficulties you are facing. [Rubén](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n) [52 mins ago](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5095/question-closed-for-lacking-detail-but-its-so-simple-i-dont-know-what-more#comment5561_5095)

It's not a reason to close.

> show the relevant question that you found on this site and explain why they don't meet your needs.  [Rubén](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n) [52 mins ago](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5095/question-closed-for-lacking-detail-but-its-so-simple-i-dont-know-what-more#comment5561_5095)

It's not a reason to close, unless the close voter found a duplicate.

> Share what you see in the Google Photos user interface including user guidance, help options, etc.  [Rubén](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n) [52 mins ago](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5095/question-closed-for-lacking-detail-but-its-so-simple-i-dont-know-what-more#comment5561_5095)

It's not a reason to close.

Answer (score 4):

Your question does not lack details or clarity. Therefore, it should not have been closed by the moderators for lacking details or clarity.

Comment: Your posts were flagged as low-effort and simply one of several examples in the last 24-hours of throwing fuel on the fire rather than contributing to a healthy debate.  We value your input but please contribute in a constructive way.

Answer (score -1):

Your Meta question's premise is that the question is so simple that you don't know any other details you can add.  Given this, posting on Meta was the right thing to do to get suggestions to improve it and I'd be happy to make some suggestions.

#### Review Prior Feedback

- A mod replied with [a comment](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5095/question-closed-for-lacking-detail-but-its-so-simple-i-dont-know-what-more#comment5561_5095) 10 minutes after you posted your question with some suggestions:

  > Please show what you have tried, explain what difficulties you are facing, show the relevant question that you found on this site and explain why they don't meet your needs. Share what you see in the Google Photos user interface including user guidance, help options, etc.

A site user posted [a comment](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5095/question-closed-for-lacking-detail-but-its-so-simple-i-dont-know-what-more#comment5562_5095) about an hour after you posted

> Is there a reason why you can't download everything and then batch delete all the photos in the folder?

#### Some Suggestions from Me

You wrote an extremely short site question that doesn't include enough details to clearly understand the problem and the type of solution you are seeking.

> I have thousands of videos and photos on Google Photos. How can I download all the videos while excluding the photos?

For example, you could provide some insight into what you already understand about the available options to download photos and videos from Google Photos and any limitations you encountered.

You could clarify if the crux of the problem is tied to the exclusion of photos or not.  For example, if you were not trying to exclude the photos, would you then know how to download the thousands of photos and videos?

You could let users know if you experienced with the available options in the web app and are looking for guidance on an API-based solution.

Questions that lack enough detail may be perfectly understood gramatically but it is more often the problem space that lacks detail and clarity.

Improving a question to include additional details helps you, helps users who might want to answer, and helps future users who might find it in a search.

Closing a question need not be permanent.  I do hope you will take the opportunity to edit it to include additional detail and then submit it for reopening.