# Why did this meta answer get removed by a mod?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answers

On the meta question [Question closed for "needs details or clarity" but it's so simple I don't know what more detail to add](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5095/18147), all 3 answers supporting the OP were deleted by a mod. One answer was undeleted by a mod a few days ago, after I pointed it out to them, but my answer is still deleted. Why?

Here is my answer:

[image]

I see the warning:

> Want to improve this post? Provide detailed answers to this question, including citations and an explanation of why your answer is correct. Answers without enough detail may be edited or deleted.

My answer is already explaining why my answer is correct.
I don't see why providing citations is required, for two reasons:

1. The mod who had closed the question didn't provide any valid citation either in the comment explaining the closure.
2. I didn't provide links explaining why those are not close reasons, because there doesn't exist such policies, and therefore such links don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer has now been undeleted Franck.

Comment: While I think this is the correct move, it doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: @Valorum While that's usually the case, here in this specific case, the moderator who closed it is the one who reopened it.

Comment: @TheMaster "*the moderator who closed it is the one who reopened it.*" On the main site, Ruben closed the question and left it closed in the review queue, while Blindspots reopened the question. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/171752/timeline

Comment: And all without a word of explanation. Most of the community effort on Meta for the last few months has been trying to undo the damage caused by a (I hesitate to use the word 'rogue', but I'm struggling to come up with a better one) moderator who decided that they were going to 'fix the site' and then tried to block any criticism of their unilateral actions.

Comment: @Valorum If the community truly doesn't want me as mod I will step down.  The context within which I took any actions informed my behavior just as the current context informs them now.  It has been suggested many times that context informed much of the behavior taken by other site users. Many of us including Franck, Galacticninja and others continue to try to move forward and heal as a  community and have displayed that through their effort. You are contributing little but poke poke poke. Either contribute in a constructive  way, or keep at it but don't expect to be given any more time.

Comment: @Blindspots There's honor in admitting a wrong openly and explaining the reasoning behind it.  As I've said before, you can't just try to hide everything and expect healing.  It'll only create stinky pus. But reversing your decision is also commendable - a step in the right direction. However, the moderator who was the most responsible, is still going on closing questions  showing absolutely no remorse for his previous actions and not reversing any of his actions.  It's better for the community, if he steps down.  Otherwise, I expect there to be continuous conflict.

Comment: @Blindspots Regarding contribution, One of the reasons, I originally reduced my webapps contribution was because of aggressive moderation back then(but that's no where near what's happening today). I used to leave code only answers, which mods didn't like. I partially agreed. However, there was one syntax related question, which simply asked where to put a comma or some character in the formula. I showed it with code and there was a comment asking to add some text. I retorted "What difference would it make, if I added the text here goes the comma" to which the mod/reviewer doubled down ...

Comment: ... essentially saying "it still helps reviewers and their time"...So, reviewers want to just review based on looks of the answer and not on the correctness of the question or answer. I was put off by such aggressive moderation and reduced  my contributions effectively. That's just my history and wanted to share with you. But I don't know how many users felt the brunt of moderation and just left. SO can afford to lose many users, but if a small site like WebApps need to survive, I believe toning down on moderation is absolutely essential, but I'm sure that moderator will not agree.

Comment: @TheMaster Only I can address my behavior & only you can address yours. I also had my feelings hurt by a mod who rebuked me for investing time & solving a problem for a user who in their estimation didn't invest enough time & the problem & solution were so specific as to be of little use to others. It took me a day or two to get over it. We lash out when our feelings are hurt & I'm sorry that happened to you. I don't know you well  but unless you hold yourself to the standards you have for others, or lower those expectations you'll continue to be disappointed & upset.

Comment: @TheMaster it is easy to cherry pick examples that justify our behavior. It's harder to do the opposite.